# Prevent click events in a FrameLayout

Tags: android, layout, click, android-framelayout

I have a `FrameLayout`, inside the `FrameLayout` I have two views, one a is a `ViewPager` and the other is a `LinearLayout`, the `LinearLayout` acts like a window, so it has some buttons. I show and hide the `LinearLayout` using the visibility property. The problem is when I show the `LinearLayout`, it covers the `ViewPager` but the user can still scroll the `ListView` inside the `ViewPager`. I want to prevent all the click events to the view behind.

The XML looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/colorBeige"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_diner_food"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout_diner_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_diner_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linea_layout_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBlackAlpha">

        <com.wonderkiln.blurkit.BlurLayout
            android:id="@+id/blurLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipChildren="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.wonderkiln.blurkit.BlurLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: My Edited Code in your question will work for you, I have also edit my answer for your question & look at that also

Comment: let me know this works or not

Comment: @NarendraSorathiya It didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

It will prevent scroll in `ListView` when you click on any part of `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/colorBeige"
      android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_diner_food"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_diner_food"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_diner_food"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linea_layout_filter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlackAlpha">

    <com.wonderkiln.blurkit.BlurLayout
        android:id="@+id/blurLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="61dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.wonderkiln.blurkit.BlurLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why a FrameLayout?

Comment: FrameLayout is basically used for Frame wise structure design. you can add Views in Frame wise. When First Frame visible, then You can not access 2nd so

Comment: FrameLayout's First Child will be at Bottom & Last Child Will be at top position

Comment: It didn't work. I changed the structure to a FrameLayout, but I can still scroll

Comment: because of TabLayout, you can scroll.
You need to create one another Ui for FrameLayout for TabFragment UI or Just for Test My code, hide tabLayout code, My code will work nicely

Answer (score 0):

Add an onTouchEvent method to the view with top position then return true. True will tell the event bubbling that the event was consumed therefore prevent event from bubbling to other views.

```
protected boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent me) {
    return true;
}
```

that to prevent scrolling underneath ListView 
And to disable any clicking you can use

```
view.setClickable(false);
```